# Cloud management and cloud brokering with Cloudify 3.0

Tags: cloudify

What is the approach of Cloudify about the Cloud management and the Cloud broker system?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudify uses a template model to describe the application blueprint - the blueprint describes  installation and post installation processes. The blueprint is completely abstracted from the underlying infrastructure. The specific mapping to the underlying infrastructure is done through a cloud driver. There are couple of built-in cloud driver implementations such as OpenStack, CloudStack, Vmware, as well as BYON. We also leverage JClouds as a generic cloud driver implementations.

The upcomming release - Cloudify 3.0 is based on TOSCA which provides a standard based blueprint implementation.

To learn more on that regard see [getcloudify.org](http://www.getcloudify.org)

Comment: when will be released the version 3.0? what will be the development language of recipes? Groovy, Python, ecc..? Thanks